# Add animation when switching tabs

Tags: angular, typescript, animation, tabs

I am working with some tabs. Is there a way to add an animation (slide left / right) when I switch tabs?

[DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/switch-tabs?file=app%2Fapp.component.html)

**code**

```
  viewMode = 'tab1';


<div class="container">
    <div class="tab-slider--nav">
      <ul class="tab-slider--tabs">
        <li class="tab-slider--trigger" [class.active]="viewMode == 'tab1'" rel="tab1" (click)="viewMode ='tab1'">Tab 1</li>
        <li class="tab-slider--trigger" [class.active]="viewMode == 'tab2'" rel="tab2" (click)="viewMode ='tab2'">Tab 2</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="tab-slider--container" [ngSwitch]="viewMode">
      <div id="tab1" class="tab-slider--body" *ngSwitchCase="'tab1'">
        <h2>First Tab</h2>
        <p>Toggle switch style tab navigation. Currently only works with two tabs.</p>
        <p>asdasd.</p>
      </div>
      <div id="tab2" class="tab-slider--body" *ngSwitchCase="'tab2'">
        <h2>Second Tab</h2>
        <p>asdad</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to use Angular Animations transitions and triggers, here is my example:

```
<body style="overflow:hidden">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="tab-slider--nav">
      <ul class="tab-slider--tabs">
        <li class="tab-slider--trigger" [class.active]="viewMode == 'tab1'" rel="tab1" (click)="viewMode ='tab1'">Tab 1</li>
        <li class="tab-slider--trigger" [class.active]="viewMode == 'tab2'" rel="tab2" (click)="viewMode ='tab2'">Tab 2</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="tab-slider--container" [ngSwitch]="viewMode">
      <div  id="tab1" class="tab-slider--body" *ngSwitchCase="'tab1'" [@slideInOut]>
        <h2>First Tab</h2>
        <p>Toggle switch style tab navigation. Currently only works with two tabs.</p>
        <p >Donec ullamcorper nulla non metus auctor fringilla. Donec ullamcorper nulla non metus auctor fringilla. Aenean eu leo quam. Pellentesque ornare sem lacinia quam venenatis vestibulum. Nullam id dolor id nibh ultricies vehicula ut id elit. Nulla
          vitae elit libero, a pharetra augue.</p>
      </div>
      <div id="tab2" class="tab-slider--body" *ngSwitchCase="'tab2'" [@slideInOut]>
        <h2>Second Tab</h2>
        <p>Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Cras mattis consectetur purus sit amet fermentum. Nulla vitae elit libero, a pharetra augue. Cras mattis consectetur purus sit amet fermentum. Aenean eu leo
          quam. Pellentesque ornare sem lacinia quam venenatis vestibulum.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

TS:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ],
    animations: [
    trigger('slideInOut', [
      transition(':enter', [
        style({transform: 'translateX(+100%)'}),
        animate('200ms ease-in', style({transform: 'translateX(0%)'}))
      ]),  
    ]),
  ]
})
```

Live example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dfaeek?file=src/app/app.module.ts

https://angular.io/guide/transition-and-triggers

Also check this out:

https://material.angular.io/components/tabs/overview

Comment: Good work ! thanks ! I was using mat-tabs-group but I was unable to place the elements to the right and center. I only got one and not both :(

Comment: In the same row, do you know if it is possible using the mat tabs to place the elements in the center, right and left, is it possible to obtain this?

Comment: You mean like this? : https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mupgsv?file=src/styles.scss

Comment: Basically I want the same as this user and I had exactly the same problem. [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60486343/mat-tab-group-aligns-items-to-the-center-right-and-left)

Comment: try this: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-kjcfx2?file=src%2Fstyles.scss

Comment: Thanks for everything ! The text I intend to keep in the center, what I intend to adjust is really the buttons (tabs left, right and center). I don't know if it's possible and it's not easy

Answer (score 0):

You can use Angular Animations transitions and triggers.
Here you can find more information :https://angular.io/guide/transition-and-triggers.